# Finding alp-point of bezier without brute force / lookup table

Tags: algorithm, bezier

I want arc-length parameterized (i.e. equidistantly spaced) points along a curve. I can loop it using de Casteljau and pythagoras. This works when the curve is static, but if the curve is dynamic it's jerky. Also I tried cubic polynomial, gave the same points as de Casteljau as expected.

Is there any way to change of one these functions to get alp-points efficently without loops/arrays? Approximations are fine.

```
float lerp(float  A, float B, float C) {
  return A*(1-C)+B*C;
}

float bezierPoint_lerp(float A, float B, float C, float D, float T) { 
  return lerp(lerp(lerp(A, B, T), lerp(B, C, T), T), 
              lerp(lerp(B, C, T), lerp(C, D, T), T), T);
}

float bezierPoint_pow(float A, float B, float C, float D, float T) { 
  return A * pow(1-T,3) + 
         B * 3 * pow(1-T,2) * T +
         C * 3 * (1-T) * pow(T,2) + 
         D * pow(T,3);
}
```

Comment: What are `alp points`?

Comment: arc length parameterized / equidistant points

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't arc-length reparameterize a curve symbolically, so your best bet is to literally mark your equidistance points *while you're drawing your curve*. Compute the curve length before you draw it, then as you draw the pixels for your curve to the screen, do an approximate distance aggregation and when you hit a coordinate that is "roughly the distance you need from the previous one", mark it in its own list. Keep doing that while you draw the curve to completion, and then at the end you have a dedicated short list of only the coordinates involved in your "alp" points.